# How to improve a double if statement

Tags: python

I would like to optimize this statement:

`if 'key' in dictionary and dictionary['key']!=value:`

Is there a way to check if a key exists in a dictionary and check the value at the same time?

Comment: `if dictionary.get('key', value) != value:`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.get()` dict method, which returns `None` if the key is not in the dictionary instead of throwing a KeyError exception:

```py
d = {'a':0,'b':1}
if d.get('a')==0:
   # you will enter this if-statement
if d.get('c')==0:
   # you will not enter this if-statement and will not throw a KeyError
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `dict` has a `get()` method. For example, if `d` is a dict, `d.get(x, y)` returns `d[x]` if it exists, otherwise it returns `y`. This means that your if statement can be replaced with `if dictionary.get(key, value) != value`.